# Is a limit a function? What about the derivative and the integral?

Tags: integration, limits

For example. If I have a function f(x) = y in the carthesian plane and it's limit exists, can I view that limit as a function with domain in R2 and codomain in R?
If that's the case, I believe that as the derivative is a limit, then it is also a function.
And what about the integral?